# If there was an md5 collision of two strings that where unsalted. Would either password work?

Tags: security, hash, md5

For example (this is not true I'm just making random md5 strings up)

if password 1's MD5 was:
MD5STRING

and password 2's MD5 was
MD5STRING

and both md5 hashs where identical, when entering a password, would either one work?

Comment: With no more infos about what you are trying to do, i would say YES as MD5 hash are identical. Maybe you have to join your MD5 password with a username or something...?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in that case it is likely that either of the the passwords may be accepted. Note that nowadays databases should contain values of a PBKDF (such as PBKDF2, bcrypt or scrypt) instead of a hash.

But if MD5 is used, then it is very unlikely that there is such a password. It is possible to generate MD5 collisions, but that won't work for very small amounts of data. A 16 character password won't ever generate a collision, you need at least an additional 16 byte block to create the collisions.

MD5 is broken, but it is not *that* broken.

Answer (score 0):

Without more specific information, the best possible answers would be as follows.

Depends on how you are handling the password.

In most cases, both passwords would work because the password is associated to a user token as a pair, so you have to match both user token and password to gain access.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your password is linked to a username / email / any unique field yes it'll work.
But keep in mind that without a salt if a hacker gets access to your database he will be able to decrypt passwords much faster.

On another note I would recommend using at the very least SHA512 instead of MD5 if you can.